# get a different user ID in php wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking for help to get a certain user ID in PHP files ( different from the one actually logged in so I can't use the WordPress function `get_curret_user_id()` ) to insert some datas about this user in the usermeta table.

Comment: What info do you have about the user? email_id? display_name?

Answer (score 1):

The `get_curret_user_id()` function will return the current users ID, i.e the one who is logged in. You need to use the `get_user_by()` function to retrieve the information of other users. You should have look at the [`get_user_by` documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/).

Answer (score 0):

get_user_by() function might be what you need.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/